# unable to Insert values in database mysql with image

Tags: php

I am trying to insert values in mysql database it seems i got stuck with this

```
Connected successfully Facebook-Cool-Profile-Pics-Boys-40.jpg 
C:\xampp\tmp\php36C9.tmp 
image/jpeg 
41015 
uploads/e98d521ff1c6360fd142d716926f92ce.jpg 

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\add.php on line 42
INSERT INTO admin(user_id,lname,fname,mname,address,contact,email_add,username,password,conf_pass,image) VALUES('1','Obemio', 'Gerald', 'G', 'USA', 09098228648, 'geraldobemio@yahoo.com', 'admin', 'pass', 'pass', 'uploads/e98d521ff1c6360fd142d716926f92ce.jpg' )Cannot be Added!
```

Heres the code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO admin(user_id,lname,fname,mname,address,contact,email_add,username,password,conf_pass,image) 
VALUES('$acctid','$lname', '$fname', '$mname', '$address', $contact, '$email',  '$user', '$pass', '$confpass', '$path' )";
$result = mysql_query($conn,$query);
echo"$query";
```

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($query); ` will be suffice.

Comment: As @AmitGarg said, you just swapped the parameters in [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Also please, don't use MySQL extension as it's deprecated, you must replace it by [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: try `mysqli_query($conn,$query)`

Comment: I tried what @AmitGarg said, i just swapped the parameters in mysql_query then the warning is gone but still the values are not inserted in the database.

Comment: i try it but still not inserted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$query = "INSERT INTO admin(user_id,lname,fname,mname,address,contact,email_add,username,password,conf_pass,image) VALUES('$acctid','$lname', '$fname', '$mname', '$address', $contact, '$email',  '$user', '$pass', '$confpass', '$path' )";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);`

Comment: i try it still not inserted .

Comment: From where you are getting this variable values? How you are storing values into variables?

Comment: I have a sign up form to filled those values..  and those values are store in variables in php

Comment: include 'pgconnect.php'; 

$acctid = $_POST['user_id'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$mname = $_POST['middlename'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$confpass = $_POST['confirmPassword'];

Comment: user_id varchar(30) NOT NULL,  lname varchar(30) NOT NULL, fname varchar(30) NOT NULL,  mname varchar(30) NOT NULL,  address varchar(50) NOT NULL, contact int(11) NOT NULL,  email_add varchar(50) NOT NULL,  username varchar(25) NOT NULL, password varchar(25) NOT NULL,  conf_pass varchar(25) NOT NULL,  image varchar(100) NOT NULL )

Comment: try  like `'".$acctid."'`

Comment: Connected successfully fb-profile-pics-attitude-for-boys-24.png 
C:\xampp\tmp\phpC112.tmp 
image/png 
89014 
uploads/2207331e42ac3e793ba83f0b9e7dbb91.jpg 
INSERT INTO admin(user_id,lname,fname,mname,address,contact,email_add,username,password,conf_pass,image) VALUES('2','Obemio', 'Gerald', 'Gomez', 'Purok 10A Camatsili St. Poblacion', 09098228648, 'geraldobemio@yahoo.com', 'admin', '1', '1', 'uploads/2207331e42ac3e793ba83f0b9e7dbb91.jpg' )Cannot be Added! still not inserted..

Comment: `fb-profile-pics-attitude-for-boys-24.png C:\xampp\tmp\phpC112.tmp image/png 89014 uploads/2207331e42ac3e793ba83f0b9e7dbb91.jpg` what's this?

Comment: do you have email? I will send my entire code for this so that you can see what i've missing or mistake?

Comment: try `INSERT INTO admin(user_id,lname,fname,mname,address,contact,email_add,username,password,conf‌​_pass,image) VALUES('2','Obemio', 'Gerald', 'Gomez', 'Purok 10A Camatsili St. Poblacion', 09098228648, 'geraldobemio@yahoo.com', 'admin', '1', '1', 'uploads/2207331e42ac3e793ba83f0b9e7dbb91.jpg' )` in phpmyadmin and let me know what error you are getting

Comment: I try it in phpmyadmin to insert using SQL and it successfully  added in the database..

Comment: send to vidhu.chel@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure for only storing your image into database you need to declare the field as BLOB, BLOB type that allows you to store binary data – images, wav files, videos etc. A frequent question developers have is regarding to storing images in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin ( user_id varchar(30) NOT NULL, lname varchar(30) NOT NULL, fname varchar(30) NOT NULL, mname varchar(30) NOT NULL, address varchar(50) NOT NULL, contact int(11) NOT NULL, email_add varchar(50) NOT NULL, username varchar(25) NOT NULL, password varchar(25) NOT NULL, conf_pass varchar(25) NOT NULL, image BLOB NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Try this one...

Answer (score -1):

$query = "INSERT INTO admin(***user_id,lname,fname,mname,address,contact,email_add,username,password,conf_pass,image***) VALUES('$acctid','$lname', '$fname', '$mname', '$address', $contact, '$email',  '$user', '$pass', '$confpass', '$path' )";

Check your data type to solve this problem.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `user_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `mname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contact` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email_add` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `conf_pass` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;